# Clean an entire fish before or after storing in a freezer?

Tags: storage-method, fish

After buying an entire fish from the supermarket, I was wondering if it is better to clean an entire fish before or after putting it to a freezer for storage (not long, abound a few days)?

Or the solution depends on the kind of fish? Today I bought some butter fishes. Before, I have bought porgy, bluefish, mackerel, pomfrey, ...

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the fish should be cleaned and prepared before being frozen. Reference: http://www.helpwithcooking.com/food-storage/freezing-fish.html

Comment: Thanks! I wonder whether the contact with water during cleaning the fish will not be good for storing the fish in the freezer?

Comment: @Tim The ice will actually protect the fish from air. Here is another good source on this: http://fishcooking.about.com/od/howtochoosefreshfish/qt/freezing_fish.htm

Comment: It has been my experience when buying commercially frozen uncleaned fish is that  cleaning it as it unfreezes and starts to rot is truly upsetting. Not recommended!

Comment: I would never buy a commercially frozen uncleaned fish. If you're going to buy an uncleaned fish it better be freshly slaughtered.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it depends on the type of fish, and how you plan cooking it.
I prefer scaling and cleaning the fish before freezing.  This way I'm only storing what I will be eating and have no need to worry about additional smells and bacteria in the freezer and whilst defrosting.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely must be cleaned before freezing.  I grew up on the shores of Lake Pontchartrain where my father was a commercial fisherman, shrimper, boat builder.  We never, froze fish without gutting and scaling them.  Same with shrimp - at least take the heads of but best to take black "vein" out and remove shells.